# MATLAB Engine: engEvalString() won't return if given incomplete input

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-engine

I'm using the [MATLAB Engine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html) C interface on OS X. I noticed that if [`engEvalString()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/engevalstring.html) is given an incomplete MATLAB input such as

```
engEvalString(ep, "x=[1 2");
```

or

```
engEvalString(ep, "for i=1:10");
```

then the function *simply never returns*. The quickest way to test this is using the [engdemo.c](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/rmvd_matlablink__0f518ce282fbd3b9ac1217f26211971d.html) example which will prompt for a piece of MATLAB code and evaluate it (i.e. you can type anything).

My application lets the user enter arbitrary MATLAB input and evaluate it, so I can't easily protect against incomplete input.  Is there a workaround?  Is there a way to prevent `engEvalString()` from hanging in this situation or is there a way to check an arbitrary piece of code for correctness/completeness before I actually pass it to MATLAB?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a time limit in c?

Comment: @Szabolcs: you deleted your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942097/accessing-matlabs-unicode-strings-from-c) from yesterday before I got a chance to post my answer. Can you please reopen it, I had a few ideas to share :)

Comment: @Amro I realized that I was stupid, and I got a reply on MATLAB Answers.  I shouldn't have used mxArrayToString at all: just get the mxChar data from the array: mxChar is a two-byte type and contains unicode data. Do you still want me to reopen ?

Comment: @Szabolcs: yes please. I show a couple of undocumented functions for unicode strings..

Comment: @Amro Sounds interesting.  [Done!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942097/accessing-matlabs-unicode-strings-from-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, it seems this bug is specific to Mac and/or Linux (I couldn't reproduce it on my Windows machine). As a workaround wrap the calls in `eval`, `evalc`, or `evalin`:

```
engEvalString(ep, "eval('x = [1,2')")
```

Furthermore, an undocumented feature of those functions is that they take a second input that is evaluated in case an error occurs in the first one. For example:

```
ERR_FLAG = false;
eval('x = [1,2', 'x=nan; ERR_FLAG=true;')
```

You can trap errors that way by querying the value of a global error flag, and still avoid the bug above...

Answer (score 0):

This was confirmed by support to be a bug in the MATLAB Engine interface on OS X (it's not present in Windows).  Workarounds are possible by using the MATLAB functions `eval`, `evalc`, or similar. Instead of directly passing the code to `engEvalString()`, wrap it in these first.